# Starting OpenOffice as service from code behind doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openoffice.org

On my development machine everything is working. But when i try on server and start it from code, OpenOffice cant connect on port 2002. If i start it from cmd with exactly same command, its working....

What i do wrong?

Cmd command

```
c:/openoffice/program/soffice.exe -headless -nologo -nofirststartwizard -norestore -accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.Service
```

From code

```
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo("c:/openoffice/program/soffice.exe")
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    Arguments = "-headless -nologo -nofirststartwizard -norestore -accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.Service" 
                };




            var result = Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: Make sure that you are either delegating user permissions or that the account running your iis has permissions to run it.

Comment: service is running in task manager..

Comment: Delegation only being an option if you're using Windows authentication, so might not apply

Comment: I misread your question, just disregard those previous comments. Although it still seems as if it might be permission related, just not execution permissions.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS Manager (IIS 7.5 here), go into Advanced Settings for the application pool your application uses. Set "Load User Profile" to True.

This seems to be required, as does `-nofirststartwizard`, which you already have.

These two things combined work for me.